# android studio doesn't accept camera.open();

Tags: android-camera

I want to add flashlight feature to my application. It will flash with a pattern. every code I found is like

```
camera.open();
```

but android studio doesn't accept

```
.open
```

part. What should I do?

Comment: Can you show your code and the stack trace of your error?

Comment: I got this code from developer.android.com     https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vjpqjii8f4ktpe/Ekran%20Resmi%202016-03-07%2016.16.58.png?dl=0

Comment: check docs missing argument on open method

Answer (score 0):

First you have add this two permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file

> 1.uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
>     2.uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"

After that in whichever class you want to use camera.open(), in that class import the following library(write following line with other import of that class in start of class)

> ***import android.hardware.Camera***

It worked for me.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer please? This won't be useful for others who may come across a similar issue.